# Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe on a clean autofac.mv5 installation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I just installed `autofac.Mvc5 6.0` on my `.net framework 4.7.2` installation.

And without adding any code other than adding the nuget package I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.6.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a or one of it's
> dependences. The found Assembly's manifest definition does not match
> the Assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have another library that uses a different version of `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`. What's in `web.config`?
Did you tried [bindingRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element)?

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

If you have a newer version replace it in the `newVersion` above.

Comment: <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.6.0" newVersion="4.0.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: Is currently in my web.config

Comment: Some dependencies of Autofac point to version `>= 5.0.0`, so maybe try changing the `bindingRedirect` to that.

Comment: Changed it to: `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />` but still having the same issue.

Comment: I just updated the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` nuget package and it worked.